# Why vector does not call destructor of pointers on clearing?

Tags: c++, vector

Consider the following two examples

```
Example A:
foo a;
std::vector<foo> vec;
vec.push_back(a);
vec.clear(); //Destructor of a is called;

Example B:
foo *b = new foo();
std::vector<foo*> vec;
vec.push_back(b);
vec.clear(); //Destructor of b is not called;
```

I would like to know know why destructor of objects in vectors are called when a vector is cleared and why destructor of pointers are not called when a vector is cleared.

Comment: A pointer has no destructor (you might use a vector of unique_ptr).

Comment: What would be the proper action to destroy a pointer `p`? Call `free(p)`, `fclose(p)`,  `delete p`, `delete [] p`, `delete [] (MyMagicType*)p`, something completely different or even doing nothing?

Comment: I know i could do that, However could you explain "A pointer does not have a destructor" . The object that the pointer points to has a destructor

Comment: @Rajeshwar: The object that the pointer points to is entirely irrelevant, and _that's the point_. You have not explained why you think a pointer going out of scope should automatically destroy the pointee.

Comment: There's your answer. A pointer is a different type than the object that it points to. That object has a destructor defined, but the pointer "object" does not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Containers only own the elements they *directly contain* - in this case the pointers. They do not own the pointees of these pointers and are thus not obliged (or even allowed) to destroy them.

You can use a `vector` of `unique_ptr`s:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<foo>> vec;
vec.emplace_back( new foo );
```

`unique_ptr`s own their pointees, and thus the `vector` who contains and owns the `unique_ptr`s subsequently also owns their pointees, and will destroy them implicitly when destroying the elements (e.g. when going out of scope).

Also have a look at [Boosts Pointer Container Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html), specifically `boost::ptr_vector`.

```
boost::ptr_vector<foo> vec;
vec.push_back( new foo );
// the object is automatically destroyed
```

Comment: In case of `boost::ptr_vector`, the memory is automatically released whenever an entry is removed from it? If so, does that mean it is internally using smart pointers (all I see is `void*` wrapped in the pointer container?

Answer (score 5):

The destructor (if you can call it that) of `b` *is* called. `b` is a pointer and it will be destroyed like any other object going out of scope.

But, like every other *pointer*, `b` going out of scope does not destroy the thing it points to. That would be incredibly dangerous and confusing. It's quite deliberate: one of the major purposes of using pointers and indirection is to *prevent* exactly that.

If you use C++11 or later, you can get this behaviour by switching to a "smart pointer" implementation, which does what you expected; by owning the pointee and ensuring that nothing else ever will, it is safe to destroy the pointee when the pointer itself goes out of scope:

```
std::unique_ptr<foo> b = std::make_unique<foo>();
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<foo>> vec;
vec.push_back(b);
vec.clear();
```

Or, better:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<foo>> vec;
vec.emplace_back(new foo);
vec.clear();
```

In C++03 you'll have to iterate over the vector and call `delete` on all its pointers, before you clear it.